# train_test_split( ) method of scikit learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I am trying to create a machine learning model using DecisionTreeClassifier. To train & test my data I imported `train_test_split` method from scikit learn. But I can not understand one of its arguments called `random_state`.

What is the significance of assigning numeric values to `random_state` of `model_selection.train_test_split` function and how may I know which numeric value to assign random_state for my decision tree?

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=324)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) mention, `random_state` is for the initialization of the random number generator used in `train_test_split` (similarly for other methods, as well). As there are many different ways to actually split a dataset, this is to ensure that you can use the method several times with the same dataset (e.g. in a series of experiments) and always get the same result (i.e. the exact same train and test sets here), i.e for *reproducibility* reasons. Its exact value is not  important and is not something you have to worry about.

Using the example in the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), setting `random_state=42` ensures that you get the exact same result shown there (the code below is actually run in my machine, and not copy-pasted from the docs):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X, y = np.arange(10).reshape((5, 2)), range(5)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

X_train
# array([[4, 5],
#        [0, 1],
#        [6, 7]])

y_train
# [2, 0, 3]

X_test
# array([[2, 3],
#        [8, 9]])

y_test
# [1, 4]
```

You should experiment yourself with different values for `random_state` (or without specifying it at all) in the above snippet to get the feeling.

Answer (score 3):

Providing a value to random state will be helpful in reproducing the same values in the split when you re-run the program.

If you don't provide any value to the random state, we will get different set of values for test and train after each run. In such a case, if you encounter any error, then it will not be helpful in debugging.

### Example:

#### Setup:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("diabetes.csv")
X=data.iloc[0:,0:8]
X.head()
y=data.iloc[0:,-1]
y.head()
```

#### Loop with `random_state`:

```
for _ in range(2):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
    print(X_train.head())
    print(X_test.head())
```

- Note the data **is the same** for both iterations

#### Loop without `random_state`:

```
for _ in range(2):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.33)
    print(X_train.head())
    print(X_test.head())
```

- Note the data **is not the same** for both iterations

If you run the code, and see the output, you will see when `random_state` is the same, it will provide the same train / test set, but when `random_state` is not provided, the set of values in test / train is different each time.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify `random_state` every time you execute your code you will get a different (random) split. Instead if you give a `random_state` value the split will always be the same. It is often used for experiments reproducibility.

For example:

```
X = [[1,5],[2,6],[3,2],[4,7], [5,5], [6,2], [7,1],[8,6]]
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)
X_train_rs, X_test_rs, y_train_rs, y_test_rs = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=324)

print("WITH RANDOM STATE: ")
print("X_train: {}\ny_train: {}\nX_test: {}\ny_test: {}".format(X_train_rs, X_test_rs, y_train_rs, y_test_rs))
print("WITHOUT RANDOM STATE: ")
print("X_train: {}\ny_train: {}\nX_test: {}\ny_test: {}".format(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test))
```

If you run this code different times you can see that the splits without random state change at every run.

As explained in the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html), `random_state` can be an integer if you want specify the random number generator seed (the most frequent case), or directly an instance of [RandomState](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.RandomState.html) class.

Answer (score 0):

random_state argument is just to seed random order. if you give different random_state it will split dataset in different order. if you provide same random_state every time then split will be same. dataset will split in same order.

If you want your dataset to split in same order every time then provide same random_state.